# mysql on ubunto 4 is not running and is not remotely accessible

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql

Currently i installed ubunot on ubunto 4.4, and using following commands i can see mysql, mysqld running

```
 ps -ef | grep mysql
 ps -ef | grep mysqld
```

but when I run, netstat i don't see mysql and 3306 anywhere. in my.cnf file, i have given my ip and port is 3306.

also when i run this command

```
sudo netstat -tap | grep mysql
```

i don't see anything and commands

I needed to run the mysql 5 on port 3306 and on ip=x.x.x.x for remotely accessible

Looking forward to your reply

Comment: ubunto? ubunot? you mean Ubuntu? It makes your question look a lot less serious if you can't even get the operating system correct!

Comment: and even if it was Ubuntu, 4.4 is not a correct version number...

Answer (score 0):

You should check the network bind address option in /etc/mysql/my.cnf

Here's some more help: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-lost-connection.html

Comment: I have followed above two urls already, but no success